# Haskell-mode source navigation for dependencies

Tags: haskell, emacs, cabal, haskell-mode, cabal-dev

I am using haskell-mode for Emacs. I succeeded at creating etags for my haskell project on every save by hasktags, however, the cabal dependencies can not be navigated to this way. So I wonder: Is there a way to make this source code navigation work for cabal dependencies, too?  (as it is easily possible for java-maven projects for example..)

Comment: For that to work, cabal would have to track the location of the source code or install it for each package you want to browse.

Comment: is there any way to make cabal download the source code?

Comment: you can use cabal unpack <package name> to download & unpack the source code in a subfolder in the current directory

Comment: cabal downloads the source code anyway when you install packages (in order to compile it). Also, emacs can peek inside these .tar.gz archives without completely unpacking them, so usually when you use emacs you can look at all the sources without further ado just by going to the cabal downloads folder and open the archives. So I guess it should be possible but propably noone has done it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [haskdogs](https://github.com/ierton/haskdogs), which provides a thin wrapper around hasktags and executes it for your imported modules as well as your own code. It maintains a repository of module sources in `~/.haskdogs` and indexes into that.

I'm using it with vi and have been quite happy with it so far.